# TypeError at /sendmail/

Tags: python, django

send_mail() missing 1 required positional argument: 'recipient_list'

In settings.py I added these lines as a setup to send an email

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'

EMAIL_PORT = 587

EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'jshrijit@gmail.com'

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '********'

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

Then in views.py I created the function to send an email

```
def index(request):

    send_mail(

        'Hello from sender',

        'Hey, how are you?.'

        'from@gmail.com',

        ['to@gmail.com'],

        fail_silently=False,

    )
```

and I got below error

> Exception Type:   TypeError Exception Value:   send_mail() missing 1
>   required positional argument: 'recipient_list'

Please help me regarding this.....

Comment: A comma is missing on the second line of `send_mail`(`'Hey, how are you?.` **,**)

Answer (score 1):

`send_mail()` 1st parameter take `subject`, 2nd parameter take `body`, 3rd parameter `from`, 4th parameter take list of `recipient` address.

You are missing `,` from 2nd parameter.
Try this

```
send_mail(
    'Hello from sender',
    'Hey, how are you?.',
    'from@gmail.com',
    ['to@gmail.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

Comment: Thanks @shafik, did as you suggested and able to send an email